# Add meta data from function for orderby in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Newbee here

I need my post to be orderby by the number of votes from a plugin named [wp ulike](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ulike/). but to get the number of votes, I need to run a function. I've tried every way I can think but didn't work.

currently here's my code:

```
<?php 
   function votecount(){
      if (function_exists('wp_ulike_get_post_likes')):
         echo wp_ulike_get_post_likes(get_the_ID());
      endif;
  }

  add_post_meta($post_id, 'votecount', $votecount);
?>

<?php 
  $ctr = 1;
  $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'ico',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'meta_key' => 'votecount',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value',
     'order' => 'DESC'
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add filter `posts_orderby`. Please take reference from below url.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198610/how-to-filter-by-last-name-for-custom-post/198624#198624